# How to be able to Freely Moving Appended Collection around in Blender 2.8

Tags: modeling

I've created a blind model in form of a Collection in Blender 2.8
Following a tutorial video on youtube. 
It's "animated/rigged". Not sure about the term.

In another model/scene/file which is a room scene, I've appended the blind model/Collection. When I tried move the Collection/model, it won't move altogether.

[image]

Comment: These might help, were done in Vers 2.77a  but should work in 2.8 - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/99821/how-can-i-shift-or-move-an-entire-animation-to-a-different-location/99911#99911 - and... - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/106609/appended-group-opening-in-original-location/107621#107621

Comment: Edgel3D, thank you very much. the second link for your second explanation seems to be the one that might suit my scene. there's no shapekeys nor graph editor.