# How to apply transforms without changing the origin?

Tags: transforms, origin

My object is far away from 0,0,0 point, it has to. The origin point also has to be in the center of my geometry. Every time I click on apply my origin goes to back to 0,0,0.

How to apply my location without changing the origin?

3D Cursor and Transform pivot point both don't work.

[image]

Comment: Are you pressing ALT+G? If so, that's clearing your location transform, not applying it. To apply it, hit CTRL+A and choose the Location option. If this isn't what you're doing, can you take a screenshot or something?

Comment: @Tumbleweed: That is what it does. You are pressing Ctr+A - Apply Location that brings an origin to Zero and keep object in location. Same if you rotate object and Apply Rotation - rotation stay but value in Rotation is set to zero. So my Q is what do you expect from "apply location"? From what you wrote object is far that is OK and has its origin in his centre, so what do you expect to act?

Comment: I expect every transform to be zero, But when I apply it to zero with "apply location", the origin will change (screenschot added)... is there no way around? Have to export for unity but the pivot will be totally messed up

Comment: It can't be :) Values represents origin position in world. Why do you need something like that?

Comment: Would this help? - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/99821/how-can-i-shift-or-move-an-entire-animation-to-a-different-location/99911#99911

Comment: Ctrl+A -> location to deltas.

Answer (score 10):

Using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> *Apply > Location to Deltas*.

will alter the delta locations such that the origin remains unchanged whilst the objects location is zeroed.

***Note** Unable to test if this works as expected when exported to Unity*

Answer (score 0):

You can move the object after going into *Edit Mode*, select all the vertexes and press <kbd>G</kbd>, or add the coordinates well after you used *Apply All Transforms*.

You don't need what you ask for, if I correctly understood.